# VBA, Get count from each sheet using multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have 10 sheets in my workbook and the 10th sheet contains names of the first 9 sheets. I was trying to create a FORMULA using VBA to get the count from each sheet.

For example, I have data in `sheet1` from range (a1:b500) and the criteria for the count is for every non-blank cell in the Column A there should be a blank cell in Column B.

Is it possible to create a UDF which takes range (a1:a500) as one array and range (b1:b500) as the second array and give the count based on the above criteria? The argument in the function should be only the sheet name – For instance, the function should take the argument as `=GetCount(sheet1)`, where `GetCount` is the function name and sheet1 is the argument.

I found the solution using loop, but I want to avoid using loop in vba, `countif` and `sum(array)` in Excel and tryout with array feature

```
Function GetCount(Str As String)
    Application.Volatile (True)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim strCount As Integer
        Set wb = Workbooks("Integrated Working Tracker")
        Set sh = wb.Sheets(Str)
        Set rng1 = sh.Range("a1:a500")
        For Each c In rng1.Cells
         If c.Value <> "" And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
         strCount = strCount + 1
         End If
        Next
    GetCount = strCount
    Set sh = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set rng1 = Nothing
End Function
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: I thing that you can accomplish that with conditional formatting, there's no need for VBA code!!! Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `sumproduct` formula.

In a cell itself, the formula would work like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A500<>"")*(B1:B500=""))
```

The individual conditional expressions, if combined in calculations, are converted to 1 or 0, and the row-wise results are then summed up.

In VBA, there is `Worksheetfunction.SumProduct`, but (as far as I remember, didn't test this now again) this does not support this 'specific' functionality (=converting boolean expressions to 1 or 0). So you have to use `Evaluate`.

```
Function GetCount(shName As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks("Integrated Working Tracker")
    Set sh = wb.Worksheets(shName)
    GetCount = sh.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((A1:A500<>"""")*(B1:B500=""""))")
End Function
```

Edit: Since `Str` is also an integrated function, I would not use it as a variable name.